# OR condition with Joins using cakephp and mysql

Tags: mysql, cakephp

Iam searching a keyword in solr and it returns matched resume id's,when I got the result from solr I am searching those documents and getting matched job seekers from my database.
Now my question is have to get the record if it match in documents or in job seekers skills i.e job_seekers.skills column how to write the query..

Here is my existing query..

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `job_seekers` AS `JobSeeker` 
LEFT JOIN `job_seeker_documents` AS `JobSeekerDocument` ON (`JobSeeker`.`id` = `JobSeekerDocument`.`job_seeker_id` AND `doc_attachment` IN ('1457448773Jan.doc',  '1457448764Eric.doc', 'Vijal_Chokshi_Profile.doc', 'Deborah_Project manager_Profile..docx'))
LEFT JOIN `config_work_authorizations` AS `ConfigWorkAuthorization` ON (`JobSeeker`.`work_authorization` = `ConfigWorkAuthorization`.`id`)
LEFT JOIN `employees` AS `Employee` ON (`Employee`.`job_seeker_id` = `JobSeeker`.`id`)
WHERE `JobSeeker`.`company_id` = 11 AND `JobSeeker`.`skills` = 'java'  AND `JobSeeker`.`bench_status` IN (0, 1) AND (select count(*) from employee_jobs where `employee_jobs`.`employee_id`=`Employee`.`id` and `employee_jobs`.`job_status` =1 ) = 0  GROUP BY `JobSeeker`.`id` HAVING (COUNT(`JobSeekerDocument`.`id`) > 0 );
```

Answer (score 0):

you can write `or` condition in brackets i.e. `()` like

```
(`JobSeeker`.`skills` = 'java'  OR `JobSeekerDocument`.`skills` = 'java')
```

In your query

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `job_seekers` AS `JobSeeker` 
LEFT JOIN `job_seeker_documents` AS `JobSeekerDocument` ON (`JobSeeker`.`id` = `JobSeekerDocument`.`job_seeker_id` AND `doc_attachment` IN ('1457448773Jan.doc',  '1457448764Eric.doc', 'Vijal_Chokshi_Profile.doc', 'Deborah_Project manager_Profile..docx'))
LEFT JOIN `config_work_authorizations` AS `ConfigWorkAuthorization` ON (`JobSeeker`.`work_authorization` = `ConfigWorkAuthorization`.`id`)
LEFT JOIN `employees` AS `Employee` ON (`Employee`.`job_seeker_id` = `JobSeeker`.`id`)
WHERE `JobSeeker`.`company_id` = 11 
AND (`JobSeeker`.`skills` = 'java'  OR `JobSeekerDocument`.`skills` = 'java')
AND `JobSeeker`.`bench_status` IN (0, 1) 
AND (select count(*) from employee_jobs where `employee_jobs`.`employee_id`=`Employee`.`id` and `employee_jobs`.`job_status` =1 ) = 0  
GROUP BY `JobSeeker`.`id` 
HAVING (COUNT(`JobSeekerDocument`.`id`) > 0 );
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.But the question is i have `JobSeeker`.`skills` column but not `JobSeekerDocument`.`skills` .I am searching those skills in the document using `doc_attachment` IN ('1457448773Jan.doc') .I have to fetch the record if skill is matched either in ('1457448773Jan.doc')  document or in `JobSeeker`.`skills` column.